# Count the number of cases in which one value is the same, but the other is not

Tags: sql, count

I have a situation where user's views and clicks on banner occur from different ip.
I log session id -- current session of page view. And I want to count how much clicks of the same session doesn't match ip of views.

Existing data:

```
date          view click    session_id          ip 
------------------------------------------------------
"2020-02-03"   1     0        111111           8.8.8.8
"2020-02-03"   0     1        111111           4.4.4.4
"2020-02-04"   1     0        222222           9.9.9.9
"2020-02-04"   0     1        222222           9.9.9.9
"2020-02-05"   1     0        333333           10.10.10.10
"2020-02-05"   0     1        333333           11.11.11.11
"2020-02-05"   1     0        444444           12.12.12.12
"2020-02-05"   0     1        444444           13.13.13.13
"2020-02-05"   1     0        555555           14.14.14.14
```

Expected output:

```
date           same_session_but_different_ip_count
---------------------------------------------------
"2020-02-03"   1
"2020-02-04"   0
"2020-02-05"   2
```

My way was to write all view sessions per month into variable `$view_sessions` and all view ip into variable `$view_ip` and count the following way:

```
SELECT 
    date, count(*)
FROM Table 

WHERE
    date >="2020-02-01" and date<="2020-02-31"
    click = 1 and
    session_id in $view_sessions and
    ip not in $view_ip
group by
    date
order by count(*)
```

Is there any more elegant way to solve this task?

Comment: I use proprietary system, that was developed for internal use.
As it's written in help:

"Universal declarative query language for data storage and processing systems with SQL-based syntax"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want two levels of aggregation.  Assuming you have only one click and view (as in the sample data):

```
SELECT date, SUM(CASE WHEN click_ip <> view_ip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM (SELECT date, session_id,
             MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'click' THEN ip END) as click_ip,
             MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'view' THEN ip END) as view_ip
      FROM Table 
      WHERE date >= '2020-02-01' and date <= '2020-02-31'
      GROUP BY date, session_id
     ) t
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: I've begun to apply your solution to my data and realized, that example was not accurate (I've fixed it). Click and view are `click=1` and `view=1`. And I have to count all `view=1 and click=1` with same session_id and different ip, but filter cases with `view=1 and click=0`
When I try to use your example, fixing select `MAX(if(CASE WHEN click = 1 THEN ip END)) as click_ip, MAX(if(CASE WHEN view = 1 THEN ip END)) as view_ip`, I get a lot of unfiltered `click_ip=null`

Comment: @MarkPolovtsev . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question, with clearer explanation and data.  Your question clearly has "same_session_but_different_ip_count",  That has nothing to do with counting clicks and views.

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select date, sum(case when mn_ip = mx_ip and mn_act <> mx_act then 1 else 0 end) as same_session_but_different_ip_count
from (select date, min(action) as mn_act, max(action) as mx_act, 
             min(ip) as mn_ip, max(ip) as mx_id
      from table t
      where date >= '2020-02-01' and date <= '2020-02-31'
      group by date, session
     ) t
group by date;
```